# ng-model is not changing after binding array element to it

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

```
<div class="ranger">
   <input type="range" max="10" min="0" step="1" id="selfRanger" ng-model="score[getPointer()]">
    <output for="selfRanger">{{score[getPointer()]}}</output>
</div>
```

I cannot change the range input element any longer. I was able to change the ranger input element with the below code.

```
<div class="ranger">
   <input type="range" max="10" min="0" step="1" id="selfRanger" ng-model="score">
    <output for="selfRanger">{{score}}</output>
</div>
```

getPointer method

```
$scope.getPointer = function()
{
    return QAPointerChange.getQAPointer();
}
```

Can anyone here please tell me what is wrong with the code?

I am actually trying to update the model with the changes from view.

Comment: Show your `getPointer()` function

Comment: @BonMacalindong added.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use `ng-model` like you have done in your first example, where you've set it to `ng-model="score[getPointer()]"`. It would be bound to different models all the time.